# Exception thrown: Write access violation C++

Tags: c++, arrays, this, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to fill (obj * m) with numbers 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20. In Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2019 I am getting this error: "Exception thrown: Write access violation" at the line "n-> val = data;" or line 15. But then I went into the DEV C ++ application and there I realized what the error was, for some reason the repetition started and the array generally deteriorated, roughly speaking, not counting the initial element. By running the program, you will see everything for yourself, I brought it up there and everything is clearly visible.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class obj{
public:
    int val, k;
    obj* next;
    obj* n;
    int current = 0;
    
    void func(int data){
        for(n = this, k=0; k<current; n = n->next,k++){
            cout<<"k= "<<k<<" = "<<n<<" = "<<n->val<<" curr= "<< current<<", ";
        }
        cout<<endl;
        n->val = data;
        current++;
    }
    
    void print(){
        for(n =this, k = 0; k<10;n = n->next,k++)
        {
            cout<<n->val<<"  ";     
        }
        
    }
};

int main() {
    obj *m;
    m=new obj [100];
    for(int i=2; i<=20;i+=2)
    {
        m->func(i);
    }
    m->print();
    delete[] m;
    cout << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: note: you never actually set `next` to anything on any of the instances of `obj`. Thus this is undefined behavior because you're just randomly looking at memory.

Comment: Did you really mean to create an array of 100 `obj` instances? Or did you mean to create an `obj` that starts off with a linked list of 100 empty nodes? Either way, the root cause is that `obj->next` points nowhere productive.

Comment: Lookup std::vector it will relieve you of much pain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `next` is not initialized, so `n` becomes to point wrong address during iteration in `func`

```
int main()
{
    /* ... snipped ... */

    /* Initialize `next` */
    for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
    {
        m[i - 1].next = &m[i];
    }
    m[99].next = nullptr;

    /* snipped */
}
```